BWS Web API bio PhotoVerify
I'm using Nestjs to access the PhotoVerify API of the BioID Developer. This is the documentation: https://developer.bioid.com/classicbws/bwsreference/webapi/photoverify
This is my bio-id.service.ts file.
import { Injectable, HttpException, Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import { HttpService } from '@nestjs/axios';
import { AxiosResponse } from 'axios';
import { firstValueFrom } from 'rxjs';
import axios from 'axios';

@Injectable()
export class BioIdService {
  private readonly endpoint = 'https://bws.bioid.com/extension/photoverify'; 
  private readonly appId = 'f57e0ab5-e4e1-41e3-8788-3ddc794f7c95';
  private readonly appSecret = 'k5ookOqYcZfYv7Bv1wSEGNzs';

  constructor(private readonly httpService: HttpService) {}

  // Función para descargar y convertir una imagen a una cadena Base64
  private async encodeImageFromUrlToBase64(imageUrl: string): Promise<string> {
    try {
      Logger.log(`Downloading image from ${imageUrl}`, 'BioIdService/encodeImageFromUrlToBase64');
      const response = await axios.get(imageUrl, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' });
      const base64 = Buffer.from(response.data, 'binary').toString('base64');
      const mimeType = response.headers['content-type'];
      return `data:${mimeType};base64,${base64}`;
    } catch (error) {
      Logger.error(`Error downloading image from ${imageUrl}: ${error.message}`, 'BioIdService/encodeImageFromUrlToBase64');
      throw new HttpException(`Error downloading image from ${imageUrl}`, 500);
    }
  }

  async photoVerify(accuracy: number, liveImageUrl: string, idPhotoUrl: string): Promise<boolean> {
    const authHeader = `Basic ${Buffer.from(`${this.appId}:${this.appSecret}`).toString('base64')}`;
    Logger.log(`Auth header: ${authHeader}`, 'BioIdService/photoVerify')
    
    const headers = {
      Authorization: authHeader,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    };

    const liveImage = await this.encodeImageFromUrlToBase64(liveImageUrl);
    const idPhoto = await this.encodeImageFromUrlToBase64(idPhotoUrl);

    const body = {
      liveimage: liveImage,
      idphoto: idPhoto,
    };

    try {
      Logger.log(`Sending request to PhotoVerify service with accuracy ${accuracy}`, 'BioIdService/photoVerify');
      
      const response: AxiosResponse = await firstValueFrom(
        this.httpService.post(`${this.endpoint}?accuracy=${accuracy}`, body, { headers }),
      );
      return response.data === true;
    } catch (error) {
      Logger.error(`Error connecting to PhotoVerify service: ${error.response?.data || error.message}`, 'BioIdService/photoVerify');
      throw new HttpException(error.message || 'Error connecting to PhotoVerify service', error.response?.status || 500);
    }
  }
}


I obtained the appId and appSecret credentials from https://bwsportal.bioid.com/
However, the API is returning a 401 which indicates that I'm not authorized. I would like to know if the way I'm creating the access basic token is correct.
this is the Request URL
http://localhost:4000/v1/bioId/photoverify?accuracy=3&liveImageUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fres.cloudinary.com%2Fsafyride%2Fimage%2Fupload%2Fv1716060705%2Fusers%2F0ab44df9-8393-4b63-a64f-8b8289a50867%2FFace.jpg&idPhotoUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fres.cloudinary.com%2Fsafyride%2Fimage%2Fupload%2Fv1716060706%2Fusers%2F0ab44df9-8393-4b63-a64f-8b8289a50867%2FNipFront.jpg
this what I´m getting: Error: Unauthorized
Response body
{
"statusCode": 401,
"message": "Request failed with status code 401"
}
this is what i expected returns the OK HTTP status code 200
